# Calling FindAll on derived classes using Castle ActiveRecord class table inheritance

Tags: c#, inheritance, castle-activerecord

I'm implementing a type hierarchy using class table inheritance.  However, I'm having trouble with the static methods returning the base type instead of the child type.  I've found a way around this but it's not too pretty.  Take the following classes

```
public class Entity : ActiveRecordBase<Entity> { }
public class Person : Entity {}
```

calling

```
Person.FindAll();
```

actually returns an Entity[] instead of a Person[].  I can get around this by implementing FindAll in all derived classes, but who wants to do that?  I was also able to create a base class that all classes derive from and implement

```
public R[] FindAll<R>() {}
```

but I just don't like the look of

```
Person.FindAll<Person>()
```

Is there any way to be able to call FindAll() from the derived classes and actually get the derived classes instead of the base class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's how .net works: there's no polymorphism for static methods. You already found a couple of workarounds, another one is *not* to rely on these static methods inherited from `ActiveRecordBase<T>`, but instead use `ActiveRecordMediator<T>` directly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could do:

```
public class Entity<T> : ActiveRecordBase<T> { }
public class Person : Entity<Person> {}
```

That way `FindAll()` would return `Person[]`

Comment: The problem with this is you can't map `Entity<T>` as it is an open generic class.

Comment: I've used this pattern before, where Entity is to be used to hold some common values (ex: id) and methods, and as a common ancestor to all entities. I don't see why you would want to map it.

Comment: @gcores: so you can put the properties of Entity in a separate class.

Comment: @Mauricio Scheffer sorry I don't follow, maybe you could expand what you mean by that?

Comment: @gcores: sorry, I meant: so you can put the properties of Entity in a separate *table*

Comment: Ok, but when you save a Person, would the properties of Entity go to that separate table too?

Comment: @gcores: yes, that's the definition of class table inheritance, which is what the OP is asking about http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html

Comment: Can you believe I managed not to read the class table inheritance bit? Otherwise I wouldn't have asked all those silly questions and just recommend the use of the non generic version of ActiveRecord. Sorry about wasting your time, one of these days I've got learn how to read.

Comment: @gcores: don't sweat it, happens to everyone. Maybe the OP prefers your solution over a class table inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

Even the documentation of *Castle.ActiveRecord* uses the workaround that you found.

**See here** for a full example and some other solutions: http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=Type%20hierarchy&NS=Active%20Record

I copied the code in case that site disappears.

**Base class** "Entity"

```
using Castle.ActiveRecord;

[ActiveRecord("entity"), JoinedBase]
public class Entity : ActiveRecordBase
{
    private int id;
    private string name;
    private string type;

    public Entity()
    {
    }

    [PrimaryKey]
    private int Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }

    [Property]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    [Property]
    public string Type
    {
        get { return type; }
        set { type = value; }
    }

    public static void DeleteAll()
    {
        DeleteAll(typeof(Entity));
    }

    public static Entity[] FindAll()
    {
        return (Entity[]) FindAll(typeof(Entity));
    }

    public static Entity Find(int id)
    {
        return (Entity) FindByPrimaryKey(typeof(Entity), id);
    }
}
```

**Derived classes** "Person" and "Company"

```
using Castle.ActiveRecord;

[ActiveRecord("entitycompany")]
public class CompanyEntity : Entity
{
    private byte company_type;
    private int comp_id;

    [JoinedKey("comp_id")]
    public int CompId
    {
        get { return comp_id; }
        set { comp_id = value; }
    }

    [Property("company_type")]
    public byte CompanyType
    {
        get { return company_type; }
        set { company_type = value; }
    }

    public new static void DeleteAll()
    {
        DeleteAll(typeof(CompanyEntity));
    }

    public new static CompanyEntity[] FindAll()
    {
        return (CompanyEntity[]) FindAll(typeof(CompanyEntity));
    }

    public new static CompanyEntity Find(int id)
    {
        return (CompanyEntity) FindByPrimaryKey(typeof(CompanyEntity), id);
    }
}

[ActiveRecord("entityperson")]
public class PersonEntity : Entity
{
    private int person_id;

    [JoinedKey]
    public int Person_Id
    {
        get { return person_id; }
        set { person_id = value; }
    }

    public new static void DeleteAll()
    {
        DeleteAll(typeof(PersonEntity));
    }

    public new static PersonEntity[] FindAll()
    {
        return (PersonEntity[]) FindAll(typeof(PersonEntity));
    }

    public new static PersonEntity Find(int id)
    {
        return (PersonEntity) FindByPrimaryKey(typeof(PersonEntity), id);
    }
}
```